# Slides template in LyX generates option clash for package graphicx

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

The `slides` template in LyX is generating an error even with a very simple example (that is, a single slide with a *.pdf plot)

The source, provided below, generates this error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package
>   graphicx.

with the following description:

> The package graphicx has already been loaded with options:   [] There
>   has now been an attempt to load it with options   [dvips] Adding the
>   global options:   ,dvips to your \documentclass declaration may fix
>   this. Try typing    to proceed.

Is there something simple I've missed? Is there a solution I can enact inside the LyX gui?

```
% Preview source code
%% LyX 2.1.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[landscape,english]{slides}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\newcounter{slidetype}
\setcounter{slidetype}{0}
\newif\ifLyXsNoCenter
\LyXsNoCenterfalse
\newcommand{\noslidecentering}{
   \LyXsNoCentertrue%
}
\newcommand{\slidecentering}{
   \LyXsNoCenterfalse%
}
\newcommand{\lyxendslide}[1]{
   \ifLyXsNoCenter%
        \vfill%
   \fi%
   \ifcase \value{slidetype}%
        \or % no action for 0
        \end{slide} \or%
        \end{overlay} \or%
        \end{note}%
   \fi%
   \setcounter{slidetype}{0}
      \visible
}
\AtEndDocument{\lyxendslide{.}}
\newcommand{\lyxnewslide}[1]{
 \lyxendslide{.}
 \setcounter{slidetype}{1}
 \begin{slide}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
% Uncomment to print out only slides and overlays
%
%\onlyslides{\slides}

% Uncomment to print out only notes
%
%\onlynotes{\notes}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

\lyxnewslide{}

Test slide.

\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm]{../../../../plot}
\end{document}
```

Comment: just delete `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` which is generating the error

Comment: I exported to source latex, made the change you suggested, re-imported to Lyx and now everything works perfectly. Thanks so much for your assistance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is too localized: it is too specific to be useful to any future visitors.

Comment: I'll defer to you, but I think this is a general problem. Simply inserting a *.pdf file into the default LyX `Slides` template replicates this error.